# Python 3,7 decoding METAR information using Re

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I've been trying to decode METAR meteo info code into a free text and have an issue. I am using `re` with `findall` function and then if anything is found i'm using indexing on strings to get a fully decoded metar message to seperate every digits and add particular words in the middle.

I'm wondering if it's possible to make the code more elegant instead of changing variable type to string and then referring to its indexes

```
import re

decoded_metar = ""
metar = "METAR XXXX 241100Z 30020KTG60 240V300 CAVOK 09/M00 Q1005 RMK 090 053 3/3="

wind = ""

wind_dir = re.compile("\d\d\d\d\dKT")
wind_speed = re.compile("\d\dKT")
wind_gusts = re.compile("G\d+")
wind_var = re.compile("\d{3}V\d{3}")

_wind_dir = str(wind_dir.findall(metar))
_wind_speed = str(wind_speed.findall(metar))
_wind_gusts = str(wind_gusts.findall(metar))
_wind_var = str(wind_var.findall(metar))

if _wind_dir == "['00000KT']":
    wind = "Wind calm. "
else:
    if len(_wind_dir) != 0:
        wind += "Wind " + _wind_dir[2] + " " + _wind_dir[3] + " " + _wind_dir[4] + " degrees "
    if len(_wind_speed) != 0:
        wind += "at " + _wind_speed[2] + " " + _wind_speed[3] + " knots. "
    if len(_wind_gusts) != 0:
        wind += "Gusting " + _wind_gusts[3] + " " + _wind_gusts[4] + " knots. "
    if len(_wind_var) != 0:
        wind += "Variable between " + _wind_var[2] + " " + _wind_var[3] + " " + _wind_var[4] + " degrees and " + _wind_var[6] + " " + _wind_var[7] + " " + _wind_var[8] + " degrees. "

print(wind)
print("End")
```

Comment: You can convert to `int` to get the values, if you put capture groups into your regexes.

Comment: Also, you really don't need a findall for METAR since each expression will only appear once in a line.

Comment: Which function instead of findall should I  use? Unfortunately I need strings and separate each digit for synthesiser pyttsx3 to speak it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use re.search(). I put detailed explanation for the used regular expresion into the code. There are alternate input strings for testing, too.

```
    import re
    metar = "METAR XXXX 241100Z 30020KTG60 240V300 CAVOK 09/M00 Q1005 RMK 090 053 3/3="
    #metar = "METAR XXXX 241100Z 30020KT   240V300 CAVOK 09/M00 Q1005 RMK 090 053 3/3="
    #metar = "METAR XXXX 241100Z 30020KT           CAVOK 09/M00 Q1005 RMK 090 053 3/3="
    #metar = "METAR XXXX 241100Z 30020KT    CAVOK   240V300  09/M00 Q1005 RMK 090 053 3/3="

    # Expected output:
    # Wind 3 0 0 degrees at 2 0 knots. Gusting 6 0 knots. Variable between 2 4 0 degrees and 3 0 0 degrees.

    mo=re.search(r"(\d{3})(\d{2})KT(?:G(\d+))?(?:.+(\d{3})V(\d{3}))?",metar)
    print(mo.groups())    
    _wind_dir, _wind_speed, _wind_gusts, _wind_var_from, _wind_var_to= mo.groups()


    def stretch(s):
        return " ".join([c for c in s])


    wind=""
    if int(_wind_dir)==0 and int(_wind_speed)==0:
        wind = "Wind calm. "
    else:
        if int(_wind_dir) != 0:
            wind += "Wind " + stretch(_wind_dir) + " degrees "
        if int(_wind_speed) != 0:
            wind += "at " + stretch(_wind_speed) + " knots. "
        if _wind_gusts and int(_wind_gusts) != 0:
            wind += "Gusting " + stretch(_wind_gusts) + " knots. "
        if _wind_var_from:
            wind += "Variable between " + stretch(_wind_var_from) + " degrees and " + stretch(_wind_var_to) + " degrees. "

    print(wind+"\nEnd")

    """
    (\d{3})(\d{2})KT    This pattern is required.
                            (\d{3}) the 1st group for _wind_dir,
                            (\d{2}) the 2nd group for _wind_speed

    (?:G(\d+))?         (...G...)? There could be a pattern with 'G' and digits, or not.
                            (?: ...) The outer group's content is not interesting.
                            (\d+) group for _wind_gusts.

    (?:.+(\d{3})V(\d{3}))?  (...V...)? There could be a pattern with 'V' and digits, or not.
                                (?: ...) The outer group's content is not interesting.
                                .+ Some not interesting patterns.
                                (\d{3}) groups for variable values.
    """
```